# Facebook API: post in domain feed

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Situation: I've the facebook like button in my website in different URLs, for example:
http://www.domain.com/object-2

Now, I get that domain Id by calling in the facebook graph api:

`/?ids=http://www.domain.com/object-2&fields=id`

and that returns me as id the same domain.

Now I want to publish as that domain, so users who liked that page, can see the status in their news feed.
I try by posting into:

`/<domain_id>/feed`

and that gives no error, and returns an id, but is just strange

```
{
    "id": "965928793449764",
    "created_time": "2015-04-16T17:38:50+0000",
    "is_scraped": false,
    "type": "website",
    "updated_time": "2015-04-16T17:38:50+0000",
    "url": "http://www.domain.com/object-2/feed"
}
```

Is this possible? Can I fix it? It was possible once, but now it doesn't work.

Thanks!

Comment: That is not a feature that exists. Create a page. Then people that like that page will see things you post on the page

Answer (score 0):

There is no `feed` edge on `domain` objects. Also, I strongly doubt that this was possible before.

See

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.3/domain